# SQL Workbench – Is it Possible to Create a Results Column based on a Shift Pattern?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

I work in a Factory that makes Components for Trucks.

We manufacture these components over 4 Rotating Shifts – named A,B,C and D.
Each Shift does 2 Weeks of Days followed by 2 Weeks of Nights.
(So the whole pattern repeats for all 4 Shifts after 28 Days)

Days are from 7am-7pm (6:59pm) and Nights are from 7pm until 7am (6:59am) the next Morning.

This Shift Pattern started in December 2019 (shown below) and is anticipated to continue for the foreseeable future.

| WEEKDAY | DATE | DAYS | NIGHTS |  | DATE | DAYS | NIGHTS |  | DATE | DAYS | NIGHTS |  | DATE | DAYS | NIGHTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | 02DEC | A | C | - | 09DEC | B | D | - | 16DEC | C | A | - | 23DEC | D | B |
| Tuesday | 03DEC | A | C | - | 10DEC | B | D | - | 17DEC | C | A | - | 24DEC | D | B |
| Wednesday | 04DEC | D | B | - | 11DEC | A | C | - | 18DEC | B | D | - | 25DEC | C | A |
| Thursday | 05DEC | D | B | - | 12DEC | A | C | - | 19DEC | B | D | - | 26DEC | C | A |
| Friday | 06DEC | A | C | - | 13DEC | B | D | - | 20DEC | C | A | - | 27DEC | D | B |
| Saturday | 07DEC | A | C | - | 14DEC | B | D | - | 21DEC | C | A | - | 28DEC | D | B |
| Sunday | 08DEC | A | C | - | 15DEC | B | D | - | 22DEC | C | A | - | 29DEC | D | B |

The information related to said components manufacture is fed into an AWS Database (Amazon Redshift) that I access with SQL Workbench.

The table that I am currently looking at is called RS_ISP_MACHINESTATUS and one of the Columns of this table is called RUN_TIMESTAMP and contains Date-Times in the format of '13-May-2019 23:09:30’.

My Question is – **is it possible to create a adjacent Results Column that provides the Shift based on the corresponding timestamp entry in the RUN_TIMESTAMP Column?**

If we take the December 2019 Pattern above - my Desired Result would be Something like:

| RUN_TIMESTAMP | SHIFT |
| --- | --- |
| 02DEC19 13:05:45 | A |
| 04DEC19 20:05:34 | B |
| 12DEC19 03:03:23 | C |

Comment: You can use a trigger to update the `SHIFT` column once the row is inserted or updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your shift pattern data just once because that pattern repeats every 4 weeks (28 days)...
MySQL code

```sql
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
WITH 
    shift_pattern (WEEKDAY, DAY_ID, DAYS, NIGHTS) AS
        (   Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-02'), DATE '2019-12-02', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-03'), DATE '2019-12-03', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-04'), DATE '2019-12-04', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-05'), DATE '2019-12-05', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-06'), DATE '2019-12-06', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-07'), DATE '2019-12-07', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-08'), DATE '2019-12-08', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-09'), DATE '2019-12-09', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-10'), DATE '2019-12-10', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-11'), DATE '2019-12-11', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-12'), DATE '2019-12-12', 'A', 'C' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-13'), DATE '2019-12-13', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-14'), DATE '2019-12-14', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-15'), DATE '2019-12-15', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-16'), DATE '2019-12-16', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-17'), DATE '2019-12-17', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-18'), DATE '2019-12-18', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-19'), DATE '2019-12-19', 'B', 'D' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-20'), DATE '2019-12-20', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-21'), DATE '2019-12-21', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-22'), DATE '2019-12-22', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            --
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-23'), DATE '2019-12-23', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-24'), DATE '2019-12-24', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-25'), DATE '2019-12-25', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-26'), DATE '2019-12-26', 'C', 'A' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-27'), DATE '2019-12-27', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-28'), DATE '2019-12-28', 'D', 'B' From Dual Union All
            Select DayName(DATE '2019-12-29'), DATE '2019-12-29', 'D', 'B' From Dual
        )
```

... with some data like in your RS_ISP_MACHINESTATUS table

```sql
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
/*
ID  TIME_STAMP
--  -------------------
 1  2019-12-02 13:05:45
 2  2019-12-04 20:05:34
 3  2019-12-12 03:03:23
 4  2020-01-19 07:00:00
 5  2023-10-05 19:00:00  */
```

Having data from above you can use the fact that the same pattern is repeating every 28 dates.
Join shift pattern and RS_ISP_MACHINESTATUS by the date difference that is multiplyer of 28 days and you could get the matching pattern row with day and night shifts. Check if hour of TIME_STAMP is day or night and select the matching shift.

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select       ms.ID, ms.TIME_STAMP, Case When HOUR(ms.TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 7 And 18 
                                        Then sp.DAYS 
                                        Else sp.NIGHTS 
                                   End as ACTIVE_SHIFT
From         shift_pattern sp
Inner Join   RS_ISP_MACHINESTATUS ms ON(1 = 1) 
Where        Mod(DateDiff(  Case When HOUR(ms.TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 7 And 18 
                                 Then DATE(ms.TIME_STAMP) 
                            Else DATE(DATE_SUB(ms.TIME_STAMP, INTERVAL '7' HOUR))  
                     -- above Else -> is a 7 hour shift in time to get the right date of the day when NIGHT shift started
                            End, 
                          sp.DAY_ID), 28) = 0
Order By   ms.ID;
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ID  TIME_STAMP           ACTIVE_SHIFT
--  -------------------  --------------
1   2019-12-02 13:05:45  A
2   2019-12-04 20:05:34  B
3   2019-12-12 03:03:23  C
4   2020-01-19 07:00:00  C
5   2023-10-05 19:00:00  B    */
```

Below is the code that show matching shift pattern rows:

```sql
--       S Q L 2 :
Select       ms.ID, ms.TIME_STAMP, Case When HOUR(ms.TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 7 And 18 
                                        Then sp.DAYS 
                                        Else sp.NIGHTS 
                                   End as ACTIVE_SHIFT, 
             --
             Concat(
                Concat('Active shift is ', Case When HOUR(ms.TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 7 And 18 
                                      Then 'DAY  '
                                 Else 'NIGHT'
                                 End), 
                ' shift from patern data >>>> ') as COMMENT,
             --
             sp.WEEKDAY, sp.DAY_ID, sp.DAYS, sp.NIGHTS
From         shift_pattern sp
Inner Join   RS_ISP_MACHINESTATUS ms ON(1 = 1) 
Where        Mod(DateDiff(  Case When HOUR(ms.TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 7 And 18 
                                 Then DATE(ms.TIME_STAMP) 
                            Else DATE(DATE_SUB(ms.TIME_STAMP, INTERVAL '7' HOUR))
                            End, 
                          sp.DAY_ID), 28) = 0
Order By   ms.ID;
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ID  TIME_STAMP           ACTIVE_SHIFT  COMMENT                                              WEEKDAY     DAY_ID       DAYS   NIGHTS
--  -------------------  ------------  ---------------------------------------------------  ----------  ----------  -----  ------
1   2019-12-02 13:05:45  A             Active shift is DAY   shift from patern data >>>>    Monday      2019-12-02  A      C
2   2019-12-04 20:05:34  B             Active shift is NIGHT shift from patern data >>>>    Wednesday   2019-12-04  D      B
3   2019-12-12 03:03:23  C             Active shift is NIGHT shift from patern data >>>>    Wednesday   2019-12-11  A      C
4   2020-01-19 07:00:00  C             Active shift is DAY   shift from patern data >>>>    Sunday      2019-12-22  C      A
5   2023-10-05 19:00:00  B             Active shift is NIGHT shift from patern data >>>>    Thursday    2019-12-05  D      B  */
```

NOTE: It should give youu expected result even for TIME_STAMPs before/after the shift pattern period (ID 4 and 5) as long as the pattern repeats as stated in the question...

Comment: Hi d r, many thanks for this! Unfortunately, the Database that I use is Read Only, so I cannot create a Shift Pattern Table using Create Table. Could I do it using a WITH Statement? Such that I'd declare the pattern once and it would then repeat forever.  (You are correct that the Shift Pattern repeats every 28 Days). Sorry if my Question is stupid, I'm still new to SQL.

Comment: @JimHiggins Yes, you can define patern data as a cte (WITH...) and it will work just the same. It could be a  problem if you need it in some other queries cause you should include the same WITH clause in each of them.

Comment: Thanks d r!
Maybe I'm pushing my luck - but can you show me how to write such a WITH Statement in this case?

Comment: @JimHiggins Just posted it instead of create table. After that code add SQL  code from the answer with a semicolon ( ; ) as the last character. You should adjust it to your context (table names - column  names - anything else...)